# Why Will Voyager Not Show my Admin Dashboard When Live? | Forge, Voyager & Laravel

Tags: laravel, forge, voyager, laravel-envoyer

I am creating a Laravel eCommerce application. I am following this tutorial on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3EbWJmmyjo&list=PLEhEHUEU3x5oPTli631ZX9cxl6cU_sDaR&index=18

For the Admin section of the website, I am using Voyager. On my localhost, everything seems to be working perfectly:

The landing page (http://localhost:8000):

[image]

When I then enter the link: http://localhost:8000/admin it takes me to the http://localhost:8000/admin/login:

[image]

I then enter these credentials (images show database as well). As you can see the credentials match and when I press login I'm taken to the dashboard:

[image]

[image]

[image]

All the screenshots so far are on my localhost. When I am trying to install Voyager on my live website it stops working! This is my live web address: https://janinevalerieaesthetics.com

I am hosting using Forge and Envoyer. And they are linking using my GitLab account: https://gitlab.com/rossi99/salonwebsite

I connect to my Forge server using ssh through my terminal using this link: ssh forge@janinevalerieaesthetics.com

And then I cd all the way into the current directory (the one that hold all my folders including the 'vendor' file and 'artisan') and then I use the php artisan commands to install the voyager package (https://voyager-docs.devdojo.com/getting-started/installation) :

1. Changing the .env file:

Installation Steps:

```
APP_URL=http://localhost
```

My .env:

```
APP_URL=https://janinevalerieaesthetics.com
```

Installation Steps:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret
```

My .env:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=forge
DB_USERNAME=forge
DB_PASSWORD="**************"
```

I thne run this command from my terminal forge@salonWebsite:~/janinevalerieaesthetics.com/current$ :

```
php artisan voyager:install
```

I then make a user from the same terminal using this command :

```
php artisan voyager:admin your@email.com --create
```

Here is my live database tables:

[image]

And here is the roles table ( you can see that user with ID 1 is the admin):

[image]

But when I navigate to https://janinevalerieaesthetics.com/admin/login it shows the login screen:

[image]

But when I log in with the correct credentials, instead of login me in and showing the admin dashboard, it logs me in and takes me to the landing page and when I try to manually get to the log in it just redirects me to the landing page:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for anyone else having this issue. When I inspected my 'seeds' directory, I did not have a 'DatabaseSeeder.php' file. I then created this by simply right-clicking and then creating DatabaseSeeder.php in mt seeds directory, I then added this code into it:

```php
<?php
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(VoyagerDatabaseSeeder::class);
    }
}
```

I then had to back into my terminal and run the following commands:

```
ssh forge@janinevalerieaesthetics.com

cd janinevalerieaesthetics.com 
(this will be your web address, to find this run command "ll -la" after ssh command)

cd current

cd database

cd seeds

vim DatabaseSeeder.php
(this will allow you to see that the most up to date seed it being used, ':q' to exit)

cd ../
(to go back to 'database' directory)

cd ../
(to go back to 'current' directory)

php artisan db:seed
(this will popuate all the roles and tables that voyager needs)

(you might see a message like this, type yes)
**************************************
*     Application In Production!     *
**************************************

 Do you really wish to run this command? (yes/no) [no]:
 > yes
```

This will then populate the database of your live site. I then tried to log in with an existing user and it didn't work. I had to create a new admin user using this command in the '/current$' directory:

```
php artisan voyager:admin admin@admin.com --create

<replace admin@admin.com with your own user email>
```

You will then be prompted for a username and password for your admin and once these are entered you can then navigate to: https://yourURL.com/admin/login and enter the details of your user and you will be navigated to you the dashboard!